# Migrating from Play 2.1 to 2.5: Build.scala configuration issues

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

I am upgrading from Play 2.1.3 to Play 2.5.4. I resolved multiple issues but I am now stuck at one last step I guess:

My `project/Build.scala`:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.sbt._
import Play.autoImport._
import PlayKeys._
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appName         = "dashboard"
    val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

    val appDependencies = Seq(
        // Add your project dependencies here,
        javaCore,
        javaJdbc,
        javaEbean
    )

    val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
        // Add your own project settings here      
    )
}
```

When I do activator run on my project, I get the following error:

```
[error] \project\Build.scala:19: object Project is not a member of package play
[error]   val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, apDependencies).settings(
[error]                   ^
[error] one error found
[debug] Compilation failed (CompilerInterface)
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

`play.Project` was replaced by native sbt Project support at version 2.3:. From this version [migration docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23):

> If you were previously using play.Project, for example a Scala project:
>
> ```
> object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
>
>   val appName = "myproject"
>   val appVersion = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
>
>   val appDependencies = Seq()
>
>   val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
>   )
>
> }
> ```
>
> ...then you can continue to use a similar approach via native sbt:
>
> ```
> object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
>
>   val appName = "myproject"
>   val appVersion = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
>
>   val appDependencies = Seq()
>
>   val main = Project(appName, file(".")).enablePlugins(play.PlayScala).settings(
>     version := appVersion,
>     libraryDependencies ++= appDependencies
>   )
>
> }
> ```

But, since you are migrating from a very old version (Play 2.1 last release was in Sep 2013), I truly recommend you to use `build.sbt` instead of `project/Build.scala`. The migration would be something like:

```
name := """dashboard"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs
)
```

And, instead of adding `javaEbean`, you will need to use [play-ebean](https://github.com/playframework/play-ebean) instead. To do so, just add the following line to your `project/plugins.sbt` file (this was [changed at Play 2.4](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24#Ebean-dependency) and you have to use the updated version as [documented for Play 2.5](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration25#Play-Ebean-upgrade)):

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "3.0.0")
```

After that, change your `root` project definition to something like this:

```
lazy val myProject = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
```

This will automatically add Ebean dependencies. Finally, I can't recommend enough that you read all the migration guides for version between 2.1 and 2.5.

Comment: Thanks Marcos for your time. Still getting the same error.

Comment: project\Build.scala:13: object PlayScala is not a member of package play
  val main = Project(appName, file(".")).enablePlugins(play.PlayScala).settings(

Comment: import sbt._
import Keys._

import play.PlayJava

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName = "myproject"
  val appVersion = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq()

  val main = Project(appName, file(".")).enablePlugins(play.PlayScala).settings(
    version := appVersion,
    libraryDependencies ++= appDependencies
  )

} This is my Build.scala

Comment: As far as my knowledge, Play 2.5.4 needs scala 2.11 or higher.

Comment: What have you tried, just changed your Build.scala or did you migrate to build.sbt?

Comment: I changed Build.scala . Now my play project compiles succesfully. But it gives exceptions while downloading sbtPlugin 2.5.4. Dependencies not found. sbtPlugin 2.5.4, scala 2.11 and sbt 0.3. It somehow isnt able to download/ find sbtPlugin dependencies.

Comment: How are you running the commands? Also, post the content of `project/plugins.sbt`.

Comment: I will only be able to do it tomorrow. Will do it first thing tomorrow morning. Thank you.  command i run 'activator compile' to compile and 'activator run' to run the project.

Comment: Ok. Which version of activator?

Comment: 1.3.10 i think....   activator version is the activator launcher jar right? 1.3.10.... is the version..

Comment: // Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Debug

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
//resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeResolver

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.5.4")

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
-------------------------------------------
This are the contents of plugins.sbt